# Получаю ошибку при установке apk "An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed"

Tags: java, android, apk, build

Сделал `build` debug apk файла пробую установить на устройство получаю такую ошибку `An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed`

Почитал, что советуют и самый простой выход это удалить приложение через настройки и уже потом установить, но этот способ не подходит так как нужно протестировать на многих устройствах более 100 и на каждом удалять нет возможности.

Странно, что это происходит с дебажным апк файлом.

Как считаете может ли быть эта ошибка из за того, что первый файл который был установлен был собран на Win , а этот файл с которым ошибка я собрал на Mac ?

Посоветуйте, что делать?

Comment: Проблема в разных подписях, а не в разных компьютерах. Поэтому где файл собирался - не суть важно, а вот какой ключ использовался для подписи - важно. Если не хотите удалять приложение на всех устройствах, то debug apk нужно подписывать тем же ключом что и release apk.

Comment: @Regent да, но я так понимаю, что ключ зависит от компьютера? 2 вопроса где хранится debug ключ и как его использовать при сборке apk debug? Ведь я просто нажимаю одну кнопку `Build APK` в Android Studio там негде не спрашивается каким ключом я хочу подписать файл... Что делать?)

Comment: А на этих 100 устройствах стоит debug apk, собранный на другом компьютере. или же release apk? Я почему-то подумал про второй вариант. Если первый, то можно просто попробовать скопировать ключ с одного компьютера на другой. Ключ может находиться здесь: `"%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`.

Comment: @Regent это дебаг, и я так понял, что все же правильный будет способ удалить старое приложение и тогда установить новый апк...

Comment: Либо удалять (особенно если это разовое событие), либо использовать одинаковый ключ. Какой вариант выбрать - решать вам. На мой взгляд, нормальными являются оба.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на Win еще есть `debug.keystore`, то скопируйте его на ваш Mac и заново соберите билд. Этот ключ создается при первой компиляции любого приложения. Он не привязан к компьютеру.

По умолчанию `debug.keystore` хранится по следующему пути:

Win XP

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\.android
```

Win 7 or higher

```
C:\Users\<username>\.android
```

Mac

```
/Users/<username>/.android/
```

Comment: Но все же я так понял, что все же правильный будет способ удалить старое приложение и тогда установить новый апк... Так как дебаг может быть разный , а вот релиз уже имеет один ключ

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko не обязательно, вы можете сделать 2 ключа, положить в проект и в сборке указать какой ключ использовать для дев или релиз сборки. да хоть 30 ключей ) Ну и соотвественно эти ключи должны шариться между всеми разработчиками.